# Update table row using codeigniter and save it in to database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Clicking on edit icon filled form should open , and proced to update

**Controller code**

```
    public function update_menus( $id ) {
    $data = array(
        'menu_title' => $this->input->post('menu_title'),
        'filepath' => $this->input->post('filepath'),
        'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
        'left_content' => $this->input->post('left_content'),
        'right_content' => $this->input->post('right_content'),
        'url_path' => $this->input->post('url_path'),
        'created_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
    if ($this->login_database->update($id, $data) == TRUE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'updated');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'not_updated');
    }
    $this->load->view('update_menus');
    $data = array();
    $data['menus'] = $this->login_database->get_menus_by_id($id);

    $this->load->view('menu_details', $data);
}
```

**Model code**

```
public function update($id)
{   
    $data = array(

            'menu_title'=> $this->input->post('menu_title'),
            'filepath' => $this->input->post('filepath'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'left_content' => $this->input->post('left_content'),
            'right_content' => $this->input->post('right_content'),
            'url_path' => $this->input->post('url_path'),
            'created_date' =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            );
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $menus = $this->db->update('menu_details', $data);
    return $menus->result();
}
```

**view code**

```
     <?php
echo form_open('user_authentication/update_menu_submit');
?><?php foreach ($menus->result() as $row) {
    ?>
    <div class="box-body">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Menu Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="menu_title" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTitle" placeholder="Enter Menu Title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Menu Url</label>
            <input type="text" name="url_path" class="form-control" id="exampleInputurl" placeholder="Enter File Path">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Upload Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="filepath" id="exampleInputFile">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputDesc">Description</label>
            <textarea id="editor4" name="description"  rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputcontl">Left Content</label>
            <textarea id="editor5" name="left_content"  rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Enter Left Content"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputcontr">Right Content</label>
            <textarea id="editor3" name="right_content"  rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Enter Right Content"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
echo form_close();
?>
</div>
```

Once click on edit action it should redirect to view page and should open filled form, Its showing error like

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codecms\application\models\login_database.php on line
>   205 in model code,

[image]

Comment: Please reformat your post here to make it readable first, I'd also suggest highlighting the specified line in your model to make it easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

can you just check the generated query using :
**$this- db- last_query();**

```
$data = array(

        'menu_title'=> $this->input->post('menu_title'),
        'filepath' => $this->input->post('filepath'),
        'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
        'left_content' => $this->input->post('left_content'),
        'right_content' => $this->input->post('right_content'),
        'url_path' => $this->input->post('url_path'),
        'created_date' =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$menus = $this->db->update('menu_details', $data);
$this->db->last_query();
```

Check the generated query in your php admin .

is return $menus->result(); required ?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\codecms\application\models\login_database.php on line 206

Comment: return $menus->result(); , in this line above error is showing.

Comment: what is there in login_database.php on line 206 ?

Comment: just comment it and try

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: menus

Filename: views/update_menus.php

Line Number: 67

Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on null in C:\

Comment: agin get the value from database and return

Comment: Em in ofc i will cmt it by eod.!!

Comment: Jus give vote for my reply and my other questions please...!!

Comment: sure thank you,, please explain model view and controller code also,,

Comment: is anybody can help me please.